# CMD FOR loop does not output the expected result

Tags: windows, for-loop, cmd

I'm learning about CMD `for` loops. I created a directory tree rooting in the folder `C:\Users\Ahmed\Desktop\Playing_Field`:

```
├───New folder - Copy
├───New folder - Copy (10)
├───New folder - Copy (11)
├───New folder - Copy (12)
├───New folder - Copy (13)
├───New folder - Copy (14)
├───New folder - Copy (15)
├───New folder - Copy (16)
├───New folder - Copy (17)
├───New folder - Copy (18)
├───New folder - Copy (19)
├───New folder - Copy (2)
├───New folder - Copy (20)
├───New folder - Copy (21)
├───New folder - Copy (22)
├───New folder - Copy (23)
├───New folder - Copy (24)
├───New folder - Copy (25)
├───New folder - Copy (26)
├───New folder - Copy (27)
├───New folder - Copy (28)
├───New folder - Copy (29)
├───New folder - Copy (3)
├───New folder - Copy (30)
├───New folder - Copy (31)
├───New folder - Copy (32)
├───New folder - Copy (33)
├───New folder - Copy (34)
├───New folder - Copy (35)
├───New folder - Copy (36)
├───New folder - Copy (4)
├───New folder - Copy (5)
├───New folder - Copy (6)
├───New folder - Copy (7)
├───New folder - Copy (8)
└───New folder - Copy (9)
```

Then I tried to filter through them using this command:

```
for /d %n in (C:\Users\Ahmed\Desktop\Playing_Field\*3*) do @echo "%n"
```

The output was:

```
"C:\Users\Ahmed\Desktop\Playing_Field\New folder - Copy (10)"
"C:\Users\Ahmed\Desktop\Playing_Field\New folder - Copy (20)"
"C:\Users\Ahmed\Desktop\Playing_Field\New folder - Copy (16)"
"C:\Users\Ahmed\Desktop\Playing_Field\New folder - Copy (13)"
"C:\Users\Ahmed\Desktop\Playing_Field\New folder - Copy (23)"
"C:\Users\Ahmed\Desktop\Playing_Field\New folder - Copy (3)"
"C:\Users\Ahmed\Desktop\Playing_Field\New folder - Copy (30)"
"C:\Users\Ahmed\Desktop\Playing_Field\New folder - Copy (31)"
"C:\Users\Ahmed\Desktop\Playing_Field\New folder - Copy (32)"
"C:\Users\Ahmed\Desktop\Playing_Field\New folder - Copy (33)"
"C:\Users\Ahmed\Desktop\Playing_Field\New folder - Copy (34)"
"C:\Users\Ahmed\Desktop\Playing_Field\New folder - Copy (35)"
"C:\Users\Ahmed\Desktop\Playing_Field\New folder - Copy (36)"
"C:\Users\Ahmed\Desktop\Playing_Field\New folder - Copy (2)"
```

Why are there some folders in the output that do not contain `3` in their names, such as `New folder - Copy (2)`?

Comment: You can also `dir /X` to see the short (8,3) names.

Comment: Okay so i understood the long/short part and that some variables can be mistaken for paramters for the function so we should steer clear from that , but i do not understand all the things on The Solution,  like   eol=| delims="  and /AD-H-L /B 2^>nul ^| 
are these in the Microsoft documentation? or a small explanation can be helpful also , and thanks for the reply @Mofi

Comment: To begin with, try `for /?` then `dir /?` in a Command Prompt window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modern Windows systems still support so-called [short file names](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-filenames.html) and even may have them enabled by default, besides the usual long files names. These short file names, also called 8.3 names (because of up to 8 characters for the base name and up to 3 characters for the extension), originate from MS-DOS and pre-Windows 95 systems, and are automatically generated in the background<sup>1</sup>.

To display such short file names, use the [`dir` command](https://ss64.com/nt/dir.html), together with its `/X` option:

```cmd
>>> dir /X /-C /A:D-H-S "%SystemDrive%\Progr*"
 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is 0000-0000

2022/07/10  19:00    <DIR>          PROGRA~1     Program Files
2022/07/10  19:00    <DIR>          PROGRA~2     Program Files (x86)
               0 File(s)              0 bytes
               2 Dir(s)    412316860416 bytes free
```

Now [wildcards](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-wildcards.html) (like `*` and `?`) match against both the long and the short file names:

```cmd
>>> dir /X /-C /A:D-H-S "%SystemDrive%\Pro*1"
 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is 0000-0000

2022/07/10  19:00    <DIR>          PROGRA~1     Program Files
               0 File(s)              0 bytes
               1 Dir(s)    412316860416 bytes free
```

---

To always match against the long file names, use [`find`](https://ss64.com/nt/find.html) or [`findstr`](https://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html) to post-filter the returned items by `dir /B`:

```cmd
>>> dir /B /A:D-H-S "%SystemDrive%\Progr*" | find /I "Program"
Program Files

>>> dir /B /A:D-H-S "%SystemDrive%\Progr*" | findstr /I /B "Program"
Program Files
```

Or, applied to your code, using [`for /F`](https://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html) to capture the result:

```cmd
>>> for /F "eol=| delims=" %I in ('dir /B /A:D-H-S /O:N "%UserProfile%\Desktop\Playing_Field\*3*" ^| find /I "3"') do @echo "%I"
"C:\Users\Ahmed\Desktop\Playing_Field\New folder - Copy (13)"
"C:\Users\Ahmed\Desktop\Playing_Field\New folder - Copy (23)"
"C:\Users\Ahmed\Desktop\Playing_Field\New folder - Copy (3)"
"C:\Users\Ahmed\Desktop\Playing_Field\New folder - Copy (30)"
"C:\Users\Ahmed\Desktop\Playing_Field\New folder - Copy (31)"
...

>>> for /F "eol=| delims=" %I in ('dir /B /A:D-H-S /O:N "%UserProfile%\Desktop\Playing_Field\*3*" ^| findstr /I "3"') do @echo "%I"
"C:\Users\Ahmed\Desktop\Playing_Field\New folder - Copy (13)"
"C:\Users\Ahmed\Desktop\Playing_Field\New folder - Copy (23)"
"C:\Users\Ahmed\Desktop\Playing_Field\New folder - Copy (3)"
"C:\Users\Ahmed\Desktop\Playing_Field\New folder - Copy (30)"
"C:\Users\Ahmed\Desktop\Playing_Field\New folder - Copy (31)"
...
```

---

<sub>1)  Note that disabling the short file names will not remove already generated such names.</sub>

Comment: Thanks for the reply  , but any idea why find does not work on my machine? find STR works as intended though 
`C:\Users\Ahmed\Desktop\Playing_Field>for /F "eol=| delims=" %I in ('dir /B /A:D-H-S /O:N "%UserProfile%\Desktop\Playing_Field\*3*" ^| find /I "3"') do @echo "%I"
find: /I: No such file or directory
find: 3: No such file or directory`

Comment: This is strange, `find` should work just like `findstr`; are you sure you copied the code as stated in the answer?

Comment: @AhmedHisham Have you installed *WinAVR* or *AVRStudio*? The installer of *WinAVR* adds its folder paths to __system__ environment variable `PATH` at beginning before `%SystemRoot%\System32`. *WinAVR* is installed with a `find.exe` being ported from Unix which interprets `/I` as directory or file and not as option. You should __Edit the system environment variables__ and move the *WinAVR* folder paths down / right after the Windows folder paths in __system__ environment variable `PATH`. Best is using in batch file `%SystemRoot%\System32\find.exe` instead of just `find`.

Comment: I have WinAvr Installed but i cant see any related variables in the PATH system variable , i've Added  `%SystemRoot%\System32\find.exe` to PATH system variable and moved it to the top, still doesnt work , i've tried
 `dir /B /A:D-H-S "%SystemDrive%\Progr*" | %SystemRoot%\System32\find.exe /I "Program"` and it worked , i tried `where find` and i got back `C:\Windows\System32\find.exe
C:\WinAVR-20100110\utils\bin\find.exe` so it seems the issue is related to what you said @Mofi

Comment: Well, `PATH` is expected to contain a semicolon-separated list of **directories** but *not* files! So it is `%SystemRoot%\System32` you should have prepended…